# Real time multi-user collaboration with Redis and JAVA on a JSON object

Tags: java, angular, redis, real-time, collaboration

I'm building an online visual editing tool (for diagrams) which uses JAVA on the backend and Redis as a database. I store JSON objects from the web app which contains the diagram width, height, position in screen, etc ...

But now I need to add a collaborative features, multiple users can edit the same diagram at the same time, which they must edit the JSON object of that diagram in our Redis database.

I need some ideas on how to achieve this using JAVA, or should I build this module with NodeJS and Socket.io ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an off-the-shelf (open source or paid) diagram editor?  That is where the bulk of the integration would need to be.  You probably have a better chance of accomplishing this by utilizing an existing real-time collaboration integration.

Simultaneous co-editing is a very difficult thing to get right. Here is an article I wrote that may shed some light on the subject: https://convergencelabs.com/realtime-collaboration-technology-guide/